# Replacing string in file iterated over list as dict value

Tags: python, html

I have a file in which i want to replace strings that are keys im substitutes dict with their values. Everything is working perfectly, however I have problem when the value of a dict is list.

Basically: I have 22 values in list3 and 22 declared ***value3*** strings in html which i want to replace with each value in list3.
i.e:

list3 = [result1, result2, result3....]

1st ***value3*** ---> result1

2nd ***value3*** ---> result2

3nd ***value3*** ---> result3

...

and then save it to variable as a string. With this I only get the last list3 value for each value3 occurence. Any ideas how to improve it?

```
def replace_html():
    substitutes = {
        'rrrrrr': string1,
        'value2': string2,
        'value3': list3,
        'value4': string4,
        'value5': string5
    }

    with open('some_html_template.html', 'r') as fin:
        html_template = []
        for line in fin:
            raw_line = line.strip()
            for key in substitutes:
                if key == 'value3':
                    for value_list in list3:
                        raw_line = raw_line.replace("___{0}___".format(key), value_list)
                raw_line = raw_line.replace("___{0}___".format(key), substitutes[key])
            html_template.append(raw_line)
        replaced_html_template = ''.join(html_template)

    fin.close()

    return replaced_html_template
```

Comment: your code is mis-formatted (quotes)?

Comment: I am not quite clear on your question, but you can extend a list into a string by doing *list, e.g. `format(key), *value_list)`

Comment: There are 22 strings: 'value3' in a file. I want to replace each of them with elements in list3.
So 1st occuerence of 'value3' will be replaced to 1st value from the list and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General idea: `re.sub` accepts callables as substitutions.
I guess something like this will work:

```
import re
import itertools

class container(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = itertools.cycle(values)

    def __call__(self, value):
        # every time this instance is called, 
        # it will return the next value in the list
        return self.values.next()

SUBSTITUTES = {  # it's better not to store data in functions
    'rrrrrr': string1,  # this one will be handled normally
    'value2': string2,
    'value3': container(list3),  # now it's callable; will loop through the values
    'value4': string4,
    'value5': string5
}

def replace_html():
    with open('some_html_template.html', 'r') as fin:
        html_template = []
        for line in fin:
            raw_line = line.strip()
            for search, replacement in SUBSTITUTES.items():
                raw_line = re.sub(search, replacement, raw_line)
            html_template.append(raw_line)

        # .close() is not necessary for with clauses
        return ''.join(html_template)
```

I guess it can be done much nicer with iterators instead of a container class but I hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, learnt a lot! However still the output: raw_line = re.sub(';;;{0};;;'.format(search), replacement, raw_line) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count) TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found. 

After changing the type of return variable of container class:
_return str(self.values[self.position])_ The result is that for each _value3_ occurence, that's 22, program replaces it with whole list3 elements. So basically now i got 22x  whole list3 elements.

Comment: sorry, the star before `*values` in `__init__` was not necessary. I also tried to cleanup the class a little bit. Please the updated version (only the class was changed)